# Put a {forest} tree inside a {philex} enviromnent

Tags: horizontal-alignment, linguistics, forest, linguex

I use the `forest`package to draw linguistic trees, and the `linguex`package to create numeric examples. But there seems to be a problem when I combine the two. The tree is not aligned with the number of the example (the XP should be aligned with (1)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. \begin{forest}
       [XP [X] [compl ] ]
     \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

If I use the `philex`package instead of `linguex`, the result is exactly the same. So the issue seems to come from the `forest`package. Has anyone any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Section 2.4.1 in the manual of `forest`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't find the information in this section... I tried to use a `\hbox`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I got it! It seems that the `baseline`option is what I was looking for. It wasn't very clear though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want that the tree is rooted at the baseline of the first item, then section 2.4.1 in the manual of `forest` says

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. \begin{forest} baseline
       [XP [X] [compl ] ]
     \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]